# Sort a table into groups of rows, where the groups are ordered by the sum in the group of a column's values - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

How can I turn this table:

```
|  User  | ItemID | Quantity | TotalValue (ValueOfItem*Quantity)  |
| UserY  |      1 |        1 |                                 15 | 
| UserX  |      2 |        1 |                                 22 | 
| UserX  |      3 |        1 |                                  7 | 
| UserY  |      3 |        1 |                                  7 | 
| UserX  |      1 |        2 |                                 30 |
| UserY  |      2 |        1 |                                 22 |
```

into this table:

```
|  User  | ItemID | Quantity | TotalValue (ValueOfItem*Quantity)  |    
| UserX  |      1 |        2 |                                 30 |
| UserX  |      2 |        1 |                                 22 |
| UserX  |      3 |        1 |                                  7 |
| UserY  |      1 |        1 |                                 15 |
| UserY  |      2 |        1 |                                 22 |
| UserY  |      3 |        1 |                                  7 |
```

I need:

- To group Users, so UserX rows are all together, and UserY rows are all together.
- Within a User's rows, the ItemID's need to be in ascending order, so 1,2,3.
- A User-group needs to be in descending order of the User's total of TotalValue.

  - ie, UserX above UserY because (30+22+7) > (15+22+7)

Comment: Your input table has 4/2 records for UserX/UserY, but your expected output contains 3/3. Please fix the wrong table.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c5a59be7acdd9708e5d6a16f1f49129)

You can calculate the sum using the [`SUM()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) per user. You can use this as an order criterion further.

```
SELECT
    user,
    item_id,
    quantity,
    total_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        sum(total_value) OVER (PARTITION BY user) as user_sum
    FROM 
        mytable
)s
ORDER BY user_sum DESC, user, item_id
```